# Using Android to Detect Signals

Tags: android, wifi, signals

I'm working on an Android application where I need to use the antenna of Android phones to detect some kind of signal.  Is there a way to detect any kind of wireless signal using Android's antenna and identify it?  Or must the signal be some sort of pre-defined one like Wi-fi?

Thanks!

Comment: What signals? There are many different types of wireless signals. Are you wanting just wi-fi?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you *can't* go as low as defining your own frequency and sending/receiving signals using it. But wait for an answer of someone who knows better than me.

Comment: ANY kind of wireless signal, any wave that I can produce from another device and have the phone detect, recognize, and identify the signal.

Comment: I highly doubt that you can pick up/add your own signals/freq in android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot receive arbitrary signals of arbitrary frequencies from the stock Android SDK. You could conceivably build an Android-powered software-defined radio, but that would require modifications to the firmware and probably the hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the same way they made the FM radio?

By using the headphone jack as an analog input, you can plug in a wire to make an antenna. You could even add an external antenna amplifier. Just a thought, but probably your best bet.

Comment: There is no FM radio in Android. Certain devices might have an FM radio tuner with a corresponding tuner chip, but that is not part of Android itself (the OS or SDK).